# 0 instances with Elastic Beanstalk Single Instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I cloned an environment which had 1 instance and was a single instance environment.

I clone it, now I have a single instance environment with 0 instances in it.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you run out of EC2 quota? You should be able to clone a single instance environment to get another single instance environment, each with 1 instance.

Comment: Just checked, I'm less than half of my limit

Comment: Are you using the web console? Can you check the events for both your environments? Do the events indicate any problem? Also if you are using the enhanced health reporting system you will see a button labeled "Health" on the left side of your console when you look at your environment. The health page will give you detailed health and possibly launch errors for the environment and instances. Can you look at the health page?

Comment: The problem was that single instance environments associate an elastic IP with it and I already used up all 5 of the IP's allocated my AWS by default. 
Not I'm deploying auto scaled elastic beanstalk instances with just one instance and it's not assigning public elastic IP's. I found this by reading over the events as you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I ran out of elastic IP addresses (you are only given 5 by default). Single instance elastic beanstalk environments WITHOUT a load balancer use an elastic IP.

I fixed this by deploying my elastic beanstalk as load balanced but set it to just have 1 instance.

This error should be displayed in the recent events.